# How to move addtocart button right sidebar in magento

Tags: magento2, layout, magento2.4.4

[image]

How to move right side add to cart in product detail page button please answer

I want to change this into

Comment: Can you elaborate more or share the screenshot or something to explain more?

Comment: Please add more details to the question. The details provided are not sufficient to help you out. Thanks!

Comment: Yes please check now, I have added screenshot